# Is there a name for the matrices with the same eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I am given a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I perform the SVD,
$$A = V \Sigma V^\top,$$
where $V$ is unitary and $\Sigma$ is diagonal. Next, I pick up another positive semi-definite diagonal matrix $\Xi$ and construct $$B = V\Xi V^\top.$$
I.e., the matrices $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors but different eigenvalues.

Is there any name for this relation? Hopefully, any nice properties for $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Simultaneously diagonalizable?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202103/does-common-eigenvectors-between-two-matrices-a-b-implies-some-property-for-the